# Using List.map to create a list of odd numbers

Tags: f#

My professor is having us create a series of functions relating to approximating pi and e based on continuing fractions. In order to set this up, he is having us create a function that takes an integer and maps that many odd numbers squared, starting from 1. For instance, here is the desired behavior:

```
oddSquares 6;; 
val it : int list = [1.0; 9.0; 25.0; 49.0; 81.0; 121.0]
```

I can see that one mapping will likely be used to square all the values in the list, but I can't figure out a way to map the number to a list of numbers. I don't want to ask anybody to write code for me, but methodically, what am I trying to do when I'm assembling the base list?

It feels like the best method is to work backwards, starting from the base number of 6 terms. We then evaluate the 6th odd term (11, or 2x-1 practically), but then require some method of recursion to continue to evaluate smaller values of oddSquares. I also think this is against the spirit of trying to map the number into these values. Can someone give me some guidance as to the first translation from the number into the list form?

Comment: You should also take a look at [sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/sequences). Contrary to lists they are lazily-evaluated and can be infinite. I think it could be useful for what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

F# offers special neat syntax for creating lists of successive numbers:

```
let oneToSix = [1..6]
```

This is a special case of something called "list comprehension". They can be more complex than just successive numbers - they can include multiple generators, filters, projections, Cartesian products, etc. In particular, your whole task of generating first N odd numbers can be expressed as one list comprehension. However, since you explicitly asked not to write the code for you, I won't.

Comment: Aha! I was incredibly close, but I never would have known to use that notation for the set. My function was just returning an empty list because duh, I was passing an empty list to map to. Now my map spans the list from [1..n]. Thank you!

let oddSquares n = List.map (fun x -> ((x*2)-1)) [1..n]

will reveal the set of odd numbers. I can figure out how to properly morph this for my assignment.